# How to call javascript function in every row during itemdatabound

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have a javascript and I need to running it every row during datagrid itemdabound. However I used the below code and it only show one time only. Would someone tell me how to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Private Sub dgrdConfirmed_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) _
  Handles dgrdConfirmed.ItemDataBound

    Select Case e.Item.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem, ListItemType.EditItem
            Dim dr As DataRow = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView).Row

           If (Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Page.GetType(), "addWarning")) Then
                Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "addWarning", 
                    "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>addWarning 
                    ();</script>")
            Else
                Dim lt As New Literal
                lt.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>addWarning()</script>"
                lt.Mode = LiteralMode.Transform


           End If
     End Select
End Sub
```

There is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function addWarning(e) {
            alert('addWarning');

        }

</script>
```

Comment: Try to rephrase you question. `ItemDataBound` is server-side event, javascript functions are executed client-side. When `dgrdConfirmedContinuedHearings_ItemDataBound` runs, there is nothing to run javascript. It will be long time still before html with javascript reaches the browser.

Comment: What does 'addWarning' do ? You could probably use jQuery to iterate the rows in the grid (which will be a table) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to loop the gridview rows in jquery not calling javascript on databound, you can use this block of code, and do not forgot to make ClientIDMode of the gridview Static :

```
$("#GridViewID tr").each(function () {
        var checkBox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        var textBox = $(this).find("input[type='text']");
        if ($(checkBox).is(':checked')) {
            if (textBox.val().length === 0) {
                alert("Warning Length 0 !!");
            }
            else {
                alert("Warning Length diffrent of 0 !!");
            }
        }
    });
```